# Going into sleep mode locks up computer

Tags: suspend

This is a fresh install of ubuntu. Im using a dell Inspiron 7405 2 in 1 laptop.
At first when it went to sleep, the screen would flash and I couldn't turn my computer back on. But now (im not sure what I did) its just a black screen. Holding the power button does nothing, I have to take the laptop apart and remove the battery for it to turn on again.
Sleeping in windows works just fine.

`lsb_release -a` :

> Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS Release:
> 20.04 Codename:   focal

`uname -a`:

> Linux ubuntu 5.13.0-30-generic #33~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mom Feb 7 1
> 4:25:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I just updated my post, i hope its enough information. I think I've seen an option to use a different kernel in grub, but it mightve just been different versions.

Comment: How do i update to 20.04.4, I updated my kernel to kernel 5.13

Comment: I did that but it says that im up to date

Comment: I'd check for warnings/messages or reboot; as an updated system will report as 20.04.4. You can look at https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/ which refers to the ISO release date, but installed systems updated about a week before the official ISO release date reflected in that notice; ie. 20.04.3 & 5.11 kernel may only apply if using an AWS cloud image which had upgrades disabled due to a problem that was fixed about a week ago & upgrades should have occurred now; but it's still possible for some to upgrade only today. AWS Cloud doesn't *suspend* though !

Comment: FYI:   I won't expend any effort on *suspend* issue given you're using a EOL kernel that upgrades will replace.  As you should be using a newer kernel, which will mean new kernel modules (aka *drivers*) I'd test the issue after upgrades; but to me the lack of an upgraded system (that may, or may-not fix the issue) is your largest concern.  Ubuntu LTS has two kernel choices; GA = 5.4, HWE = 5.13 at 20.04.4 (plus OEM options too) but 5.11 is *outdated* & EOL.  Your provided details (*if accurate*) highlight to me a more important issue!

Comment: Alright, i will do that. Should i move this into a chat?

Comment: @guiverc i have updated my compter and my post showing the new details. Im having the same issue

Answer (score -1):

It seems like this is a common issue with dell inspirions. I was able to fix it by following this guide : https://dev.to/epassaro/fix-suspend-issues-on-dell-7405-2-in-1-3l1b
I also had to shut off secure boot to make it work.